# why vtable doesn't use hash Table

Tags: objective-c, runtime

In objective-c `struct _class_t` has two fields `void *cache` and `void *vtable`. `Cashe` uses hash table, but `vtable` uses pointer offset to find method. So why `vtable` doesn't use hash table.

Comment: See here:  http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2011/06/17/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_vtable.html

Comment: A vtable is faster, because it is indexed (with hard-coded indexes.) This is only for the most commonly used methods. 'cache' simply caches (ok, you thought so) used methods so you do not need to look up the class tree the next time, the selector is sent.

Comment: Whether cache more useful for subclass which invoke superclass methods. But  it is useless for subclass own methods. So if it waste for memory. @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: No, since it is more likely that a selector is sent that already has been sent. Therefore looking up the cache is faster.

Comment: I can't understand.Can you introduce more detailedly, or recommend an associated article. Thanks a lot. @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: Since programs tend to do the same thing over and over again, it is likely that an object that received a selector `doSomething` will receive `doSomething`again. Esp. it is more likely to receive `doSomething` again than receiving `doAnotherThing`. "Wasting memory" is no issue on modern computers. Please, keep in mind that there are only two caches per class. (One for the instance object, one for the class object). This isn't wasting memory, but peanuts even if you have thousands of classes.